# have multiple lines in the same graph in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Please I need help I have been able to plot a graph using

```
df = pd.Series(data1, name='y').rename_axis('x').reset_index()
    df.plot(kind='scatter' , x='x' , y='y' )
```

for a dictionary type `{'2022-01-30': 50, '2022-01-31': 152, '2022-02-01': 41 }`

How can i have it multiple data/dictionary i.e. different values but the same key e.g.

```
data1 = {'2022-01-30': 50, '2022-01-31': 152, '2022-02-01': 41 }
data2 = {'2022-01-30': 124, '2022-01-31': 142, '2022-02-01': 745 }
data3 = {'2022-01-30': 4, '2022-01-31': 1, '2022-02-01': 7 }
```

Also how can i label the lines drawn within the graph

Comment: where do other values like `124`, `1`, `7 ...` come from?

Answer (score 4):

You might just want to build the DataFrame in a different way and use a line plot (not scatter):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([data1, data2, data3]).T.rename_axis(index='x', columns='y')

df.plot()
```

Output:

[image]

If you also want labels for the lines, add them from a list:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame([data1, data2, data3], index=['data1', 'data2', 'data3'])
        .T.rename_axis(index='x', columns='y')
     )
df.plot()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If need set labels of each column create DataFrame by constructor with dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'2022-01-30': 50, '2022-01-31': 152, '2022-02-01': 41 }
d2 = {'2022-01-30': 124, '2022-01-31': 142, '2022-02-01': 745 }
d3 = {'2022-01-30': 4, '2022-01-31': 1, '2022-02-01': 7 }
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': d1,'b': d2, 'c': d3})
```

If need pass lists of labels and list of DataFrames:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(['a','b','c'], [d1, d2, d3])))
print (df)
              a    b  c
2022-01-30   50  124  4
2022-01-31  152  142  1
2022-02-01   41  745  7
```

Last plot by [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.plot()
```

[image: pic]